# What is wrong with the implementation of NSCoding protocol in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I thought I'd be cautious and try out Swift on an existing Obj-C project by converting one class. And a small, simple one at that. Oh dear.

Transliterating the original obj-c into Swift should be straightforward and so it seemed. Unfortunately, whilst the encoder to persistent store seems to work, it crashes with an EXC_BREAKPOINT error at the first line of the init coder.

IF (and the caps are intentional) NSCoding/Swift gives the same persistent content as NSCoding/ObjC, then my all obj-c version should be able to read what is encoded by Swift and vice versa. This proves not to be the case - and my perfectly-functioning obj-c version crashes out when it tries to read the persistent store from the Swift version. Surely, if NSCoding is implemented correctly, it ought to generate something in one that is readable in t'other? Otherwise, there ought to be separate NSCodingSwift and NSCodingObjC protocols?

So, to summarise, I can read/write in obj-c. I can't write/obj-c and read/swift and I can write/swift read/obj-c and I can't read/write in swift.

Here are the two versions:

```
let keyBeaconItemNameKey = "name"
let keyBeaconItemUUIDKey = "uuid"
let keyBeaconItemMajorValueKey = "major"
let keyBeaconItemMinorValueKey = "minor"

import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class SMBeaconItem : NSObject, NSCoding
{
    var name : String!
    var uuid : NSUUID!
    var major : NSNumber!
    var minor : NSNumber!

    init(newName : String, newUUID : NSUUID, newMajor : NSNumber, newMinor : NSNumber )
    {
        name = newName
        uuid = newUUID
        major = newMajor
        minor = newMinor
    }

    init( coder decoder : NSCoder!)
    {
        name = decoder.decodeObjectForKey(keyBeaconItemNameKey) as String
        uuid = decoder.decodeObjectForKey(keyBeaconItemUUIDKey) as NSUUID
        major = decoder.decodeObjectForKey(keyBeaconItemMajorValueKey) as NSNumber
        minor = decoder.decodeObjectForKey(keyBeaconItemMinorValueKey) as NSNumber
    }

    func encodeWithCoder( encoder: NSCoder!)
    {
        encoder.encodeObject(name, forKey:keyBeaconItemNameKey)
        encoder.encodeObject(uuid, forKey:keyBeaconItemUUIDKey)
        encoder.encodeObject(major, forKey:keyBeaconItemMajorValueKey)
        encoder.encodeObject(minor, forKey:keyBeaconItemMinorValueKey)
       }
    }
```

And the working original:

```
@implementation SMBeaconItem

- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)name uuid:(NSUUID *)uuid major:(CLBeaconMajorValue)major minor:(CLBeaconMinorValue)minor
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    _name = name;
    _uuid = uuid;
    _majorValue = major;
    _minorValue = minor;

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Persistence

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (!self)
    {
        return nil;
    }

    _name = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:keyBeaconItemNameKey];
    _uuid = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:keyBeaconItemUUIDKey];
    _majorValue = [[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:keyBeaconItemMajorValueKey] unsignedIntegerValue];
    _minorValue = [[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:keyBeaconItemMinorValueKey] unsignedIntegerValue];

    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:keyBeaconItemNameKey];
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.uuid forKey:keyBeaconItemUUIDKey];
    [aCoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:self.majorValue] forKey:keyBeaconItemMajorValueKey];
    [aCoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:self.minorValue] forKey:keyBeaconItemMinorValueKey];
}

@end
```

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: Perhaps the brave, but anonymous person who down voted this would be gracious enough to explain? I have done several hours of research and it is relevant. Not all of us have the time to re-write all our code in swift and yet are making serious attempts to move with the times. If you're so clever tell me what I didn't do.

Comment: It works for me, encoding ObjC to Swift, and Swift to Objc.  I see nothing wrong with the code you've posted.  The problem could be related to how you're setting up the NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver.  If it's failing in ObjC there should be more error information on the debug console.

Comment: Thanks, Darren. If I comment out the attempt to read back the name property (and set the value to a literal) then it works. The rest of init works fine. The only info on the debug console is the error EXC_BREAKPOINT with code = 1 and sub code = 0x1000a26e0, which I can't find an explanation of.

Comment: My guess would be that it's because your swift class names are mangled, try putting @objc(SMBeaconItem) just before your class declaration.

Comment: Thanks, David. I'd tried that and it doesn't fix it. It definitely does something, because if you put something else like @objc(SMWeirdName) the app crashes before it gets to the init coder saying it doesn't know how to dearchive SMBeaconItem. My instinct says the problem is actually in the encoder, because it dearchives everything except the name property.

Comment: Post the code that calls the encoding and decoding.

Comment: Why don´t you call Super in the Init methods when you are subclassing NSObject - You should maybe not subclass NSObject? or call super?

Comment: Well, I don't know what _should_ be wrong with the code but sometimes the code does only work using the **self.** keyword in front of the variables. I do not know the reasons for that but this has appeared to myself several times so far.

Comment: By the way the init with coder actually has to have the keyword `required`but I don't know if you had to use it in older versions of Swift

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that stands out to me is that you're using `String` instead of `NSString` as the `name`'s type. In the betas Apple has been putting out, `String` (strangely) is not a one-for-one replacement of `NSString`. Namely, some methods are missing and require calling `.bridgeToObjectiveC()` to get the `NSString` version. Using that type instead will probably conform to what `NSCoder` is expecting, though that difference should not be so.

I didn't actually test this claim since I'm not on my dev machine. But that's my gut instinct. Try it and see what happens! If nothing changes, try switching the order of how you're setting the vars and see if it's a problem related to the `name` field or simply the first line of the init function.

Comment: Do not use `bridgeToObjectiveC()`. Use `(thing as NSString)` instead.

Comment: Yup, that's good advice @JackLawrence. But, if they want/need to use `String` though, a good way to have both types is the bridge.

Comment: @Nick any luck with this solution?

Comment: `(thing as NSString)` and `(thing as String)` call `bridgeToObjectiveC()`. The `bridgeToObjectiveC()` function is meant to be private API to support those bridged casts.

Answer (score 0):

Below code working is swift for save retrieve NSCoding value in UserDefaults

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var employees: Employees?
    let static_key = "nscdeing_data_saved"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees")!, cachePolicy: .returnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 60)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if let status = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode, status == 200, let data = data{
                do {
                    guard let dic = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any] else { return }
                    self.employees = Employees.init(fromDictionary: dic)
                    let archiveData = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self.employees as Any, requiringSecureCoding: true)
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(archiveData, forKey: self.static_key)
                } catch let error {
                    fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    @IBAction func printAction(_ sender: Any) {
        if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: static_key){
            do {
                let value = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data)
                print(value as Any)
            } catch let error {
                fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}

class Employees : NSObject, NSCoding, NSSecureCoding{
    static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool{
        return true
    }

    var data : [Datum]!
    var status : String!
    /**
     * Instantiate the instance using the passed dictionary values to set the properties values
     */
    init(fromDictionary dictionary: [String:Any]){
        status = dictionary["status"] as? String
        data = [Datum]()
        if let dataArray = dictionary["data"] as? [[String:Any]]{
            for dic in dataArray{
                let value = Datum(fromDictionary: dic)
                data.append(value)
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the available property values in the form of [String:Any] object where the key is the approperiate json key and the value is the value of the corresponding property
     */
    func toDictionary() -> [String:Any]{
        var dictionary = [String:Any]()
        if status != nil{
            dictionary["status"] = status
        }
        if data != nil{
            var dictionaryElements = [[String:Any]]()
            for dataElement in data {
                dictionaryElements.append(dataElement.toDictionary())
            }
            dictionary["data"] = dictionaryElements
        }
        return dictionary
    }

    /**
     * NSCoding required initializer.
     * Fills the data from the passed decoder
     */
    @objc required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        data = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "data") as? [Datum]
        status = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "status") as? String
    }

    /**
     * NSCoding required method.
     * Encodes mode properties into the decoder
     */
    @objc func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder){
        if data != nil{
            aCoder.encode(data, forKey: "data")
        }
        if status != nil{
            aCoder.encode(status, forKey: "status")
        }
    }
}
class Datum : NSObject, NSCoding, NSSecureCoding{
    static var supportsSecureCoding: Bool{
        return true
    }

    var employeeAge : String!
    var employeeName : String!
    var employeeSalary : String!
    var id : String!
    var profileImage : String!

    /**
     * Instantiate the instance using the passed dictionary values to set the properties values
     */
    init(fromDictionary dictionary: [String:Any]){
        employeeAge = dictionary["employee_age"] as? String
        employeeName = dictionary["employee_name"] as? String
        employeeSalary = dictionary["employee_salary"] as? String
        id = dictionary["id"] as? String
        profileImage = dictionary["profile_image"] as? String
    }

    /**
     * Returns all the available property values in the form of [String:Any] object where the key is the approperiate json key and the value is the value of the corresponding property
     */
    func toDictionary() -> [String:Any]{
        var dictionary = [String:Any]()
        if employeeAge != nil{
            dictionary["employee_age"] = employeeAge
        }
        if employeeName != nil{
            dictionary["employee_name"] = employeeName
        }
        if employeeSalary != nil{
            dictionary["employee_salary"] = employeeSalary
        }
        if id != nil{
            dictionary["id"] = id
        }
        if profileImage != nil{
            dictionary["profile_image"] = profileImage
        }
        return dictionary
    }

    /**
     * NSCoding required initializer.
     * Fills the data from the passed decoder
     */
    @objc required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        employeeAge = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "employee_age") as? String
        employeeName = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "employee_name") as? String
        employeeSalary = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "employee_salary") as? String
        id = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "id") as? String
        profileImage = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "profile_image") as? String
    }

    /**
     * NSCoding required method.
     * Encodes mode properties into the decoder
     */
    @objc func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder){
        if employeeAge != nil{
            aCoder.encode(employeeAge, forKey: "employee_age")
        }
        if employeeName != nil{
            aCoder.encode(employeeName, forKey: "employee_name")
        }
        if employeeSalary != nil{
            aCoder.encode(employeeSalary, forKey: "employee_salary")
        }
        if id != nil{
            aCoder.encode(id, forKey: "id")
        }
        if profileImage != nil{
            aCoder.encode(profileImage, forKey: "profile_image")
        }
    }
}
```